# CadMouse Pro Wireless stops working 2-3 secs after plugging in via USB (18.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, usb, mouse

I'm on vanilla Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I just got a [CadMouse Pro Wireless](https://www.3dconnexion.com/cadmouse_pro_wireless/en/). This mouse has two modes - it can be used in wireless mode via a USB receiver dongle, or it can be used in wired mode by plugging it directly into the computer via a microUSB cable.

In wireless mode, it works fine.

In wired mode, after plugging it in, the following happens:

- For the first 2 - 3 seconds, it works fine.

  - When I physically move the mouse, the cursor on the screen moves appropriately.
  - When I physically click the buttons, the on-screen interface elements (buttons, menus, etc) respond appropriately.
- After 2 - 3 seconds, it stops working.

  - When I physically move the mouse, the cursor on the screen doesn't move.
  - When I physically click the buttons, on-screen interface elements don't respond at all.

I've verified the mouse works fine in both modes in Windows 10 and macOS.

Here's the `dmesg` output when plugging in the mouse:

```
daniel@ubuntu:~$ dmesg -w
[10758.269137] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[10758.608911] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=256f, idProduct=c654, bcdDevice= 1.06
[10758.608913] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10758.608915] usb 1-3: Product: CadMouse Pro Wireless
[10758.608916] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: 3Dconnexion
[10758.635675] input: 3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro Wireless as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:256F:C654.001C/input/input44
[10758.636070] hid-generic 0003:256F:C654.001C: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro Wireless] on usb-0000:03:00.0-3/input0
[10758.648184] input: 3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro Wireless as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:256F:C654.001D/input/input45
[10758.648408] hid-generic 0003:256F:C654.001D: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Multi-Axis Controller [3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro Wireless] on usb-0000:03:00.0-3/input1
```

No further messages appear after the mouse stops working.

Here's the `lsusb` output after plugging in the mouse:

```
daniel@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 256f:c654  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`256f:c654` is the CadMouse Pro.

(the Logitech receiver is for a different, unrelated mouse that works fine. I observe the same behavior for the CadMouse whether or not the Logitech receiver is plugged in).

I've also been trying to approach this via the HID API via `cadmousectl`, but haven't had much success there because HID API can see but not open the CadMouse - see [GitHub](https://github.com/lachs0r/cadmousectl/issues/7) issue for more information.

Any ideas how I can get the mouse to not stop responding after 2 - 3 sec? Thanks.